# Strncpy test fail

Tags: c, string, copy

I`m trying to test this strncpy function and I am really frustrated because it produces wrong results. Here is some output when trying to compile on command-line:

To be orHo?

Help will be appreciated.

Here is the code:

```
/* strncpy example */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char *
STRNCPY(char * dst, const char *  src, size_t n)
{
    if (n != 0) {
        char *d = dst;
        const char *s = src;

        do {
            if ((*d++ = *s++) == 0) {
                /* NUL pad the remaining n-1 bytes */
                while (--n != 0)
                    *d++ = 0;
                break;
            }
        } while (--n != 0);
    }
    return (dst);
}

int main ()
{
  char str1[]= "To be or not to be";
  char str2[40];

  /* partial copy (only 5 chars): */
  STRNCPY ( str2, str1, 8 );

  puts (str2);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: "*Wrong*" in which sense?

Comment: you have to null terminate your strings